# Termination implies existence of normal form

Tags: coq, proof

I would like to prove that termination implies existence of normal form. These are my definitions:

```
Section Forms.
  Require Import Classical_Prop.
  Require Import Classical_Pred_Type.
  Context {A : Type}
  Variable R : A -> A -> Prop.

  Definition Inverse (Rel : A -> A -> Prop) := fun x y => Rel y x.  

  Inductive ReflexiveTransitiveClosure : Relation A A :=
  | rtc_into (x y : A) : R x y -> ReflexiveTransitiveClosure x y
  | rtc_trans (x y z : A) : R x y -> ReflexiveTransitiveClosure y z ->
                            ReflexiveTransitiveClosure x z
  | rtc_refl (x y : A) : x = y -> ReflexiveTransitiveClosure x y.

  Definition redc (x : A) := exists y, R x y.
  Definition nf (x : A) := ~(redc x).
  Definition nfo (x y : A) := ReflexiveTransitiveClosure R x y /\ nf y.
  Definition terminating := forall x, Acc (Inverse R) x.
  Definition normalizing := forall x, (exists y, nfo x y).
End Forms.
```

I'd like to prove:

```
Lemma terminating_impl_normalizing (T : terminating):
  normalizing.
```

I have been banging my head against the wall for a couple of hours now, and I've made almost no progress. I can show:

```
Lemma terminating_not_inf_forall (T : terminating) :
  forall f : nat -> A, ~ (forall n, R (f n) (f (S n))).
```

which I believe should help (this is also true without classic).

Comment: The question is well posed. However, I can't easily copy and paste this into my Coq editor. There are syntax errors and missing definitions.  Would you mind preparing the code so that it is easier for others to give a shot at proving the Lemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof using the excluded middle. I reformulated the problem to  replace custom definitions by standard ones (note by the way that in your definition of the closure, the `rtc_into` is redundant with the other ones). I also reformulated `terminating` using `well_founded`.

```
Require Import Classical_Prop.
Require Import Relations.

Section Forms.
  Context {A : Type} (R:relation A).

  Definition inverse := fun x y => R y x.

  Definition redc (x : A) := exists y, R x y.
  Definition nf (x : A) := ~(redc x).
  Definition nfo (x y : A) := clos_refl_trans _ R x y /\ nf y.
  Definition terminating := well_founded inverse. (* forall x, Acc inverse x. *)
  Definition normalizing := forall x, (exists y, nfo x y).

  Lemma terminating_impl_normalizing (T : terminating):
    normalizing.
  Proof.
    unfold normalizing.
    apply (well_founded_ind T). intros.
    destruct (classic (redc x)).
    - destruct H0 as [y H0]. pose proof (H _ H0).
      destruct H1 as [y' H1]. exists y'. unfold nfo.
      destruct H1.
      split.
      + apply rt_trans with (y:=y). apply rt_step. assumption. assumption.
      + assumption.
    - exists x. unfold nfo. split. apply rt_refl. assumption.
Qed.

End Forms.
```

The proof is not very complicated but here are the main ideas:

- use well founded induction
- thanks to the excluded middle principle, separate the case where `x` is not in normal form and the case where it is
- if `x` is not in normal form, use the induction hypothesis and use the transitivity of the closure to conclude
- if `x` is already in normal form, we are done